# String Convert into double in swift 4.1

Tags: swift, casting

```
let getLongijson: String = "67.0011"
let getlatijson: String = "24.8607"

let jsonlong = (getLongijson as NSString).doubleValue
let jsonlat = (getlatijson as NSString).doubleValue
```

Error i am Facing this
    Cannot use instance member 'getLongijson' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available

Comment: post all your relevant code if your error message is that, that means that your issue is not related to String conversion, is about init instead

Comment: just this error i am facing

Comment: try to convert in sting to double

Comment: because longi late come form json the long late value is in string

Comment: if your error message is **Cannot use instance member 'getLongijson' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available** this means that you have an issue in your init method

Comment: thats why i need to convet string to double  not converted

Comment: i am not using any init method

Comment: As pointed out above, the problem is not the conversion from string to double, but that you have properties whose initialization depends on other properties of the same type. – You'll find more than 40 similar question with answers with a SO search for `[swift] property initializers run before 'self' is available`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You like this to convert `String` into `Double`:

```
let getLongijson: String = "67.0011"
let getlatijson: String = "24.8607"

let jsonlong = Double(getLongijson)
let jsonlat = Double(getlatijson)
```

Comment: This is the correct, Swift, method, but be aware that `jsonlong` and `jsonlat` will be optionals - ie `Double?`

Comment: @Paulw11 Yes, Thank you